# Laravel Virtual Columns fail to save

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I added a couple of virtual columns to my database tables using Laravels `virtualAs` column modifier:

```
 $table->decimal('grand_total')->virtualAs( '(total_value + (total_value*tax_rate))');
```

Basically it keeps a mysql virtual column that automatically calculates the grand total based on the total and tax rate stored in another column.

However, Laravel does not seem to play nice with virtual columns at all. When saving a record, it attempts to `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the virtual column, which is obviously not allowed in mySQL. I could not find a way to configure in the Eloquent model which fields are actually written to the database on an update or insert.

I've tried adding the field to the models `$hidden`, and `$appends` but nothing seems to work.

Looking at the Laravel Source code for an insert (https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.6/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php#L733), it seems to just insert whatever attributes are in `$this->attributes`. When the record is read from the database the `grand_total` field is read from the table and set as an attribute and then it is tried to be written again once the record is saved.

Is there any way to get this Laravel to stop trying to save columns that are virtual?

Comment: Hidden and appends aren't for updates, they're both for manipulating the array results in toArray

Comment: I don't see anything documented for support of virtual fields in Eloquent.  I can think of an easy fix by applying a filter to $attributes before executing save though.

Comment: The only thing I could think of would be to use an [observer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#observers), and unset the attribute on saving.

Comment: @aynber How would I restore the value then after the save? It seems like I would have to either re-fetch the record from the database, or add logic to calculate the virtual columns values which defeats the whole purpose of virtual columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick trait I wrote to solve your problem that will filter fields residing in the $virtualFields property before saving.  It requires a select (refresh) after the save to get the new value for the virtual field.   If you don't need to query this virtual field, I'd highly recommend you look into a mutator instead.

```
trait HasVirtualFields 
{
     public function save(array $options = [])
     {
          if (isset($this->virtualFields)) {
              $this->attributes = array_diff_key($this->attributes, array_flip($this->virtualFields));
          }

          $return = parent::save($options);
          $this->refresh(); // Refresh the model for the new virtual column values
          return $return;
    }
}

class YourModel
{
    use HasVirtualFields;
    protected $virtualFields = ['grand_total'];
}
```

Comment: Awesome solution. Works great! I never thought to override the save method itself and I was trying to hook into the saving/saved events. Your solution works great. ...Also for anyone else reading this, it looks like mariaDB will silently ignore values inserted into virtual columns as discussed in this thread (https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79148) which means this problem can also be avoided by using mariaDB instead of mysql.

Comment: Yeah, you could hook into saving and saved separately (one for filtering, one for refreshing), but I thought overriding save was easier.

Comment: @Brad, one thing to note, if you use mariadb and it ignores the value, you'd still have an outdated value for your virtual field (if it changed) in the model until you refresh it.